# Require external module in Typescript internal module

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd

As the title suggests I have an internal module in which I require an external module (in this case momentjs)
If I just have the module definition and reference this in my other files it compiles fine but of course at runtime I get a 'moment is not defined' error.
If I then add:

```
import moment = require('moment');
```

then the module gets wrapped in the appropriate require([.....]) code but now my other files won't compile due to the module reference not being found.

What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, make sure you have the moment TypeScript definition file included in your project and referenced.

[TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

You can include moment as follows:

```
var moment: moment.MomentStatic = require('moment');
```

Comment: I see I was using the require syntax incorrectly for my needs. Works perfectly - Thanks!